# My Makefile just doesnt work.

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which is just not working. Can you guys help me to find where the error is? Thanks!

```
CC = gcc
FILES = workfile.c insert.c
TARGETS = exe
CFLAGS = -o
DBUG =
RM = rm -f
OBJS = *.o

#Master Rule

all: $(TARGETS)

#Build

exe: workfile.o insert.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) workfile.o insert.o exe

#workfile

workfile.o: workfile.c
    $(CC) $(DBUG) -c *.c

insert.o: insert.c
    $(CC) $(DBUG) -c *.c

clean:  
    $(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)
```

The error is as follows

```
$make all
gcc  -c *.c
gcc -o  workfile.o insert.o exe
gcc: error: exe: No such file or directory
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

I even tried changing the names of the targets. But did not help. Could not continue further.

Comment: You have specified `exe` as one of the inputs here `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) workfile.o insert.o exe`. Is this intended ? Maybe you meant `-o exe`

Comment: @luk32 yes it was intended. :)

Comment: If you intended that then `exe` must exist before the rule can run. You simply misplaced the `-o` option.

Comment: @Shash Really ? exe is part of the input? Cause it seems like you have misplaced the -o and `exe` is the output filename not part of the input files =P

Comment: @luk32 I just could use my makefile and it is now working fine. I meant to thank you good folks previously. I have deleted my confusing comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to put `-o` in `CFLAGS`, I would rather to remove `-o` from it.

`CFLAGS = -o` -> `CFLAGS =`

Now you can work on your `exe`, the output path should follow `-o` immediately.

```
exe: workfile.o insert.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) workfile.o insert.o exe
```

=>

```
exe: workfile.o insert.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) -o exe workfile.o insert.o
```

So the full makefile should look like:

```
CC = gcc
FILES = workfile.c insert.c
TARGETS = exe
CFLAGS =
DBUG =
RM = rm -f
OBJS = *.o

#Master Rule

all: $(TARGETS)

#Build

exe: workfile.o insert.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) -o exe workfile.o insert.o

#workfile

workfile.o: workfile.c
    $(CC) $(DBUG) -o workfile.o -c workfile.c

insert.o: insert.c
    $(CC) $(DBUG) -o insert.o -c insert.c

clean:  
    $(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CFLAGS` is used wrongly. The `-o` option should go before `exe` and the `CFLAGS` should contain relevant flags for the compiler (`-O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` for example).

Try this:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

exe: workfile.o insert.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) workfile.o insert.o -o exe
```

PS: You can strip the `DBUG` and stick the `-g` in `CFLAGS` when needed. This is how it is used in normal Makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Uh i got it... you have an `-o` in there in cflags. I think you shouldn't use `-o` in `CFLAGS` because it expects a parameter.

The important part that could be changed:

```
CFLAGS = 
OUTFILE = fancy_exe
[...]
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBUG) workfile.o insert.o -o $(OUTFILE)
```

This should work better... or even skip the outfile varaible and put exe by hand.